# React form not submitting when using button nested inside Link tag

Tags: reactjs, button, react-router-dom

In my app I have an order form with a button to "complete order" at the bottom. What I want the button to do is submit the form and push the user to the confirmation page where their order will be displayed. Right now I can do one or the other, but can't figure out how to to both.

My form component:

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <label>Name:
        <input 
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    </label>
    <Link to="/confirmation" >
        <button>Complete Order</button>
    </Link>
</form>
```

My onSubmit function:

```
const formSubmit = () => {
  const newOrder = {
    name: formValues.name.trim(),
  }

  setOrder(order.concat(newOrder));
  setFormValues(initialFormValues);
}
```

I can tell my formSubmit function submit isn't working because my formValues don't reset after form submission. If I remove the Link tag and just have the button, they do, but then I don't get the redirect to the confirmation page. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update/reset the form state ***then*** navigate to the `"/confirmation"` path, you can't use a `Link` and a `button`/submit the form at the same time.

Remove the `Link` component and issue an imperative navigation *after* enqueueing the state updates. Don't forget to prevent the default form action from occurring so the app isn't reloaded.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newOrder = {
    name: formValues.name.trim(),
  };

  setOrder(order.concat(newOrder));
  setFormValues(initialFormValues);
  navigate("/confirmation");
}

...

<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <label>Name:
    <input 
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Name"
      value={values.name}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Complete Order</button>
</form>
```